# Placing multiple data frames in a single map layout in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, data-frame

I am trying to prepare a layout for my study area by method showing country to state to city in ArcGIS Pro, but all the data frames are showing the same area and when I try to change the data, the data in all the data frames is getting changed.
How do I add different data frames in a single layout in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing an ArcMap terminology and concept of data franes with the ArcGIS Pro terminology and concept of map frames.

Think of a map frame being like a window onto a map.  If one map frame is to show different layers to another then it needs to be linked to a different map.

If you want the same layers in each map frame, but just a different extent for each, then use the Contents pane to Activate each map frame in turn and your zoom/pan (Explore) tools to set the extent you want, before closing the activation.

Comment: Hii @PolyGeo  I'm using different shapefiles and ESRI's base map. if I'm enabling one shapefile in one map frame automatically the data in all the map frames are changed. Same happened with zooming the data by activating the map frame. I have tried it previously in ARC Map but there I did not face this problem. Now i don't have ArcGIS installed and I wanted to learn how it's done in Pro.